# Output of mathematical function in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am a complete novice when it comes to vba but I want to help a friend out, so I could use some guidance with a problem. I figure something like this is on the internet already, but I cannot find it, so if you have a suggestion as to where I could look, I would appreciate it.

I have a vba project with 19 modules, which compiles with no errors or warnings. The program calculates economic rate of return, given certain events. All the results come out as they should, apart from a single one. I am all but certain, that there is a mathematical flaw with this particular input, but I cannot locate it. This leads me to my question:

How can I obtain output from a (mathematical) function defined in vba?  Preferably for discrete values of time, but at this point any help will do.

Comment: Have a look at this page which has a guide to creating a user-defined function: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: Look up 'debugging in VBA'. Step through your code line by line and work out the issue

Comment: Put the cursor in a `Sub` or `Function` with no arguments (the driver) and press `F8`. Now you can step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call it. You can do it from a cell in a spreadsheet:

Assuming the function is called myMathematicalFunction and takes one parameter:

A1:

```
=myMathematicalFunction(B1)
```

B1:

```
<input value to test>
```